# Unable to start program, the system cannot find the file specified

Tags: c++

My code is just normal like the one below

```
#include <iostream> 

using namespace std;

int main()

{

return 0;

}
```

but i don't know why this happens
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oa4q9.png)
I also noticed that there is something wrong with the "source file" thing and 457 errors have been found:
**[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xfr0Q.png)**

Im a newbie in vs and I have spent hours on this problem, pls help me.

Note: I did the build solution, the Single startup project but the errors are still there :((

UPDATE: well, after a long time dining in this error, I can finally fix it. The main reason is I did not download the SDK. I want to thank persons who are willing to help me out with this problem, without your help I my stuck forever. Again thank you very much.

Comment: Please mention you actual  code snippets here rather than image for more readability. Thanks

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please take a [tour] and see [ask]. Specifically: [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors). Also please format your code properly.

Comment: Glad you found a solution. For the benefit of future readers, please don't edit it into your question. Either accept one of the existing answers or write an answer yourself. Self-answering is encouraged on SO. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

**Check the solution explorer**
On the toolbar in the left, or whereever your solution explorer is located, make sure your file is saved within the current project. You may be trying to run the file without it being in the project. Make sure you add new files by clicking (add new) or manually attaching them to the project.

Update on whether this works for you.

Also, if you're getting include errors, try rebuilding the project and see if that helps with the includes. Have you ran projects in the past and had them compile correctly? Are you in Windows? This may be an issue with not having downloaded the SDK if not, but don't think it goes that deep.

Here is a link with a similar issue from the VS forum:
[VS forum, source issue](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/1367007/error-in-visual-studio-2019-cant-open-source-file)

After doing some more digging, it may actually be the SDK issue if you haven't gotten the code to compile in the past. Need more info.

Comment: Actually, I have compiled once but when I reopened the folder, some error appeared so I decided to reinstall the VS and the thing just happened like above.
Also, I just checked and found out I didn't download the SDK thing so now I'm doing it, hope it'll work

Comment: I think it might be the SDK then. Rerun the installer and install the SDK.

Edit: Good to hear! Let me know. It's needed for even just the standard library apparently because it includes the runtime.